# Next.js router params keeps giving me unknown key warnings

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, url-parameters, next-router

Im creating a search page so I am using the URL params to handle the filters, such as product category and price.

This is my current method that handles adding and removing the URL params:

```
 function handleCheck(checked: Boolean, id: string, option) {
    if (checked) {
      if (router.query[id]) {
        router.query[id] += `,${option.value}`;
      } else {
        router.query[id] = `${option.value}`;
      }
    }
    if (!checked) {
      if (router.query[id]) {
        let param = router.query[id].toString();
        let array = param.split(",");
        array = array.filter((param) => param !== option.value);
        router.query[id] = array;
      }
    }
    router.push(router);
  }
```

**I get these warnings everytime the URL changes:**

[image]

Comment: Is this relevant: https://github.com/vercel/next.js/issues/7962

Comment: Why are you passing the router instance itself to the [`router.push`](https://nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/next/router#routerpush) call? Its first argument should either be a string or URL object.

Comment: I believe I saw another example here on stack overflow that suggested pushing the entire object. Should i try with just the router.query? @juliomalves

Comment: Yeah, as a string. I would also recommend you not to mutate `router.query`, and generate a new query string to pass to `router.push`.